# mongoose populate reference returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am fairly new to mongoose so I have probably missed something here.

I have two Collections "Company" & "User" I am trying to get all Users who belong to a company but The users array on the company is returning undefined instead of what I would expect to be the user objects.

I have read through the documentation and populate seemed to be a step in the right direction however, it doesn't mention at any stage (that I could see) how to save into an array I assume I need to push the objects to the emails property on the user object?

I come from a very mysql heavy background and I maybe doing somethings incorrectly would appreciate if someone could explain how MongoDB handles relationships?

Company Schema

```
const companySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    slug: String,
    _creator: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    users: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Company', companySchema);
```

User Schema

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    companies: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company' }],
    created_at: Date,
    updated_at: Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Save the user

```
const dave = new User({
    first_name: 'Dave',
    last_name: 'Hewitt',
    username: 'moshie',
    password: '123456789',
    updated_at: new Date()
});

dave.save()
    .then(function (user) {
        const indigoTree = new Company({
            name: 'IndigoTree',
            slug: 'indigotree',
            _creator: dave._id,
            updated_at: new Date()
        });

        indigoTree.users.push(user);

        return indigoTree.save();
    })
    .then(function (company) {
        console.log(company);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Check the user

```
Company.find({}).populate('users').exec()
   .then(function (doc) {
       doc.users // undefined?
   });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing `user` into the `users` array. Instead of that you need to `push` `user's Id` into the array i.e. `user._id`.

**Replace:**

```
indigoTree.users.push(user);
```

**With:**

```
indigoTree.users.push(user._id);
```

Also, `find()` query returns `array of documents`, so you need to use `doc[0].users`, not `doc.users`.

```
Company.find({}).populate('users').exec()
   .then(function (doc) {
       doc[0].users // undefined? -> change here, it wont come undefined
   });
```

**Alternatively**, you can use `findOne()` instead of `find()`, which returns an `object`. In that case you can use `doc.users`

```
  Company.findOne({_id: someCompanyId}).populate('users').exec()
   .then(function (doc) {
       doc.users // it wont come undefined
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [API Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html), Mongoose's `find()` returns an array collections instead of single item.

> For findOne() it is a potentially-null single document, find() a list of documents, count() the number of documents, update() the number of documents affected, etc

```
Company.find({}).populate('users').exec().then((doc) => {
    console.log(doc[0].users); // prints users array
});
```